# Import a list from a single cell of Excel Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am using xlrd package and I want to import lists from excel spreadsheet which are written in single cells (comma separated or space separated), just like the spreadsheet below:

[image]

I want to import those machine sequence values in four different lists, such that my expected output would look like the following:

```
M1 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
M2 = [1,5,9]
M3 = [2,5,1,4,9,4]
M4 = [7, 4]
```

Should I format the spreadsheet in any better way to do this?
Please help.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: It should be,
M1 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
M2 = [1,5,9]
M3 = [2,5,1,4,9,4]
M4 = [7, 4]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import xlrd


main_book = xlrd.open_workbook('machine_sequence_excel_file.xlsx')
main_sheet = main_book.sheet_by_index(0)   # assuming that the data is in the first sheet

M1, M2, M3, M4 = [[int(y) for y in x.split(',')] for x in main_sheet.col_values(1)[1:]]

# M1
# [2, 4, 6, 8]

# M2
# [1, 5, 9]

# M3
# [2, 5, 1, 4, 9, 4]

# M4
# [7, 4]
```

Essentially, what is happening here is that you are reading the values of the second column, starting with the second the value. This is done by invoking the `col_values` method of the `Sheet` object. Subsequently, you then `split` each value on the comma to generate lists whose values are coerced into integers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's is what I wanted ! :)